# How can I plot a scatter graph and plot a prediction line for two features in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, logistic-regression

I am trying to predict y based on two features held inside X. After reading my excel file and splitting my data into columns, my X value looks like this:

```
     SibSp  Parch
0        1      0
1        1      0
2        0      0
3        1      0
4        0      0
5        0      0
6        0      0
7        3      1
8        0      2
9        1      0
```

`y` denotes survival rate, 1 being survived, 0 being died. X has many many more rows. I am using `train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=101)` to get training and testing data splits and have a method to train and test. My training code looks like this:

```
def train():
    # Get Data Split
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = initData()

    # Create LinearRegression Instance
    lm = LinearRegression()

    # Fit Training Values
    lm.fit(X_train,y_train)

    visualise(X_test, y_test, lm.predict(X_test))

    # Return Trained Data With Testing Data
    return X_test, y_test, lm
```

My testing code looks like this:

```
def test():
    # Get The Trained Classifier
    X, y, lm = train()

    # Fit New Values
    lm.fit(X, y)

    visualise(X, y, lm.predict(X))
```

Which, appears to work fine - or so I think. I am now trying to visualise the data as a scatter plot with the prediction line plot.

```
def visualise(X, y, predictions):
    features = X.shape[1]
    colors   = ['red', 'blue']
    i        = 0
    while i <= features -1:
        plt.scatter(X.iloc[:, i], y, color=colors[i])
        # Update: Forgot to add this line when posting question
        plt.plot(X.iloc[:, i], predictions, color=colors[i])
        i=+1
```

But this is giving me crazy outputs with lines going everywhere. I tried to look online and found [sklearn's example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-linear-model-plot-ols-py). This is me trying to replicate this:

I thought that maybe, because I have two features, I may need to identify them separately.

```
def visualise(X, y, predictions):
    newY = np.zeros(X.shape[0], X.shape[1]);
    newY[:, 0:1] = newY.iloc[:, 0]
    plt.scatter(X, y, color='blue')
    plt.plot(X, predictions, color='red')

    plt.xticks(())
    plt.yticks(())

    plt.show()
```

I had to create a newY array since X has two features, y had 1 so the shapes where different. But now I am getting an error at the line `newY = np.zeros(X.shape[0], X.shape[1]);`

> TypeError: data type not understood

**Update**

```
def visualise(X, y, predictions):
    newY = np.zeros((X.shape[0], X.shape[1]));
    newY[:, 0] = y
    newY[:, 1] = y
    plt.scatter(X, newY, color='blue')
    plt.plot(X, predictions, color='red')
```

Now fixes the error, but this is my output:

[image]

How can I plot my scatter graph and plot a line for my predictions?

Comment: Please at least provide a reason for the down-vote, I provided a MCVE, everything I have tried, research and I'm still trying? But the lines are going mental

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have two features you can't draw a prediction line. If anything you probably want a prediction contour plot.

Your example is much more similar to this two-featured example here
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_iris.html

Comment: Could I predict with each feature, calculate the overall prediction score, ie Feature 1: 0.3456.. 2: 0.256434 so overall will be 0.3 and then draw a line like that? Or would it make more sense to join these values together and call it 'Family', since SibSP is siblings, Parch is spouses, to make it one feature?

Comment: You could hold one of the variables constant then plot the prediction as a function of the other variable. You have to think about what will be on the x and y axes of your plot. If the prediction is on the y axis then only one variable can be plotted on the x axis. This is why I suggested a contour plot; the variables could be plotted on the x and y axes with the colour representing the predicted value.